# Application like http://www.hootsuite.com and twitter api

Tags: twitter

I am creating an twitter application (using asp.net mvc4) which will handle over 1 million twitter users. App is basically a clone of https://hootsuite.com/ .  App will provide an interface for user to view/update tweets.

Can anyone tell me what api should I use to achieve the desired result without crossing the api limits. I am planning to use rest and streaming api (using tweetsharp and tweetInvi wrappers)

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it all depends on what you intend to do.
With more than a million users, you will need to request tokens from your users.
And use these Tokens to perform the operations you want.

You need to provide a little bit more details concerning what you want to do.
But in any case try to use the Stream as much as you can otherwise the rate limits will quickly be crossed.